# Como llamar al utlimo registro de una tabla en Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Tengo dos tablas, mi tabla principal **Tabla1** donde esta la lista de paises y mi **Tabla2** donde esta las fecha de viaje. lo que quiero es traer a mi tabla1 la ultima fecha de viaje de dicho pais.

Tabla 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la formula que estoy poniendo es el **LOOKUPVALUE**

```
 fecha ultimo=LOOKUPVALUE('Tabla2'[fecha viaje],'Tabla2'[pais],'Tabla1'[pais])
```

pero me sale el error que hay duplicidad de registros. como haria para tomar el ultimo registro de dicho pais. osea el de la fecha mayor?

Comment: Hablas de tablas de datos? o de tablas en el informe? Si es en el primer caso, lo debes hace en Power Query mediante "Merge Queries", si es en el segundo debes tener las tablas relacionadas: país con país

Comment: es el segundo caso. pero si los tengo relacionados podre obtener la ultima fecha?

Comment: Entiendo que en la Tabla 1 solo hay un registro por país, entonces si.

Comment: y con que funcion traigo a mi tabla 1 la fecha mayor de la tabla 2

Comment: Mis disculpas, no entendí bien tu problema, a ver si la respuesta que te propongo te sirve como solución.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si logro entender y darle solución. Disponemos de una tabla física que contiene dos columna: País, Fecha de viaje. Existen varios paises y en cada uno de ellos pueden existir varios viajes.

Deseamos tener una tabla en el informe que nos indique la última fecha en la que se realizó un viaje a cada país.

Tabla de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Construimos una fórmula (medida) en la misma tabla que nos indique la fecha máxima por país, la llamaremos "Último viaje":

```
Último viaje = Maxx(Viajes,Viajes[Fecha Viaje])
```

Luego construimos un visual de tipo tabla donde ponemos el país y la medida "Último viaje:":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Roger, habra manera de ponerlo como columna en mi tabla1, lo que pasa es que hay algunos paises que no tienen registros de viaje, y otros que el viaje se ha dado en hace mas de 1 año. entonces yo quiero tener en mi tabla1 una columna que me indique esos tres casos: VIGENTE, NO VIGENTE Y NO REALIZADO. esto me servira para poder mostrarlo en una grafica y ver cantidades

Comment: roger puede apoyarme con esta consulta?